# Преобразование штрих-кода в строку c#

Tags: c#, excel, штрихкод, barcode

В общем я программно обрабатываю документы *.xlsx и из нужных полей вынимаю нужные мне данные.

Теперь появилась следующая задача: В полях могут быть штрих-коды в виде картинок, которые мне нужно обработать и записать в строку.

Как это сделать? Выслушаю любые ваши предложения.

**P.S.** Для обработки документов использую библиотеку Aspose. Если через нее это можно реализовать - расскажите что для этого там есть.

**Пример** (Все штрих-коды с надписями - это картинки)**:**
[image: Штрих-коды]

Comment: Вариант 1 - искать библиотеки.

Comment: Вариант 2-  распознать полоски. Меремасштабировать так, что б преобразовать в "двоично-прерывистый код" т.е. в 1101 - стартовый код первого ШКИ, почитать стандарты - и подставить значения с таблицы используя стандарт.

Comment: Ваш ШКИ очень похож на CODE-128. Вероятнее всего - это он и есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a это очень сильно упростит задачу если это окажется CODE-128 ?

Comment: Я думаю лучше искать что то конкретное, чем что то общее. Стандартов ШКИ одномерных около 20 штук. Проще найти более конкретное, чем общее.

Comment: Если вы можете преобразовать картинку в двоично-прерывистый код - я кину ссылку на таблицу перевода - и ваша задача решена. Если нет - 1. Ищите библиотеку, 2. Пытаетесь писать что-то своё.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

Comment: Не знаю платная это либа или нет, пробуйте http://www.barcodelib.com/aspnet_barcode_reader/barcodes/code128.html

Comment: @nick_n_a к сожалению вариант с библиотекой отпадает, так что вкусно пока что выглядит вариант с преобразованием картинки в двоичный код и потом в строку. Поделитесь ссылкой на таблицу перевода пожалуйста

Comment: Таблица вот http://www.barcode.kiev.ua/types_c128.html их три штуки. Первый символ должен быть от 103 до 105, в зависимости от этого выбираете столбец.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, пока что буду с этим разбираться, если никто ничего больше не предложит

Comment: У вас   2 1 1 4 1 2  - Start A , а потом у вас если не ошибаюсь 
2 1 3 1 1 3  -  как раз символ S. Далее последняя ссылка даёт возможность расшифровать "вручную". Про цифры - тоже ссылка.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что в вашем случае имеет смысл строить велосипед, есть большое количество библиотек распознающих штрих-коды с изображений, в некоторых даже не обязательно заранее указывать тип штрих-кода.

Comment: @yolosora ну.. приведите парочку.

Comment: Ещё описание http://www.barcodeisland.com/code128.phtml